# Excel - Nth occurence

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically I'd like it to work this way.

```
DataColumn    Nth Occurence
A                  1
B                  1
C                  1  
A                  2
A                  3
B                  2
B                  3
C                  2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIF()

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

And copy down